# How to properly handle RecyclerView adapter in scene animation

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation

I have two scenes to animate. The Scene1 includes RecyclerView, the Scene2 includes 2 EditText. When I use TransitionManger to animate transition from Scene1 to Scene2 everything works fine. When I go back to the Scene1 I got empty RecyclerView.

I guess it happens because of new inflating of Scene1 layout. In this case no adapter attaced to RecyclerView.
In this case do I need reattach recycler adapter every time I go back to Scene1 or it can be done in other way?

[image: scene transition]

Answer (score 0):

Do you call `finish()` method to finish your activity/fragment before going to scene 2? Then you need to re-initialize everything, from view-to-data.

Comment: No, I do not use finish() in my activity. I do animation without any finish() method.

Comment: I guess I have to reinitialize recyclerview adapter. I try this way and it works like a charm, but looks so ugly.